# Adding overlay buttons to tvOS AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

I'm trying to build an overlay that appears over an AVPlayer when I press pause. The problem I'm having is that while I can overlay buttons just fine I can't get the focus engine in tvOS to focus on them... I'm pretty sure this is happening as the player frame robs focus (it's fullscreen @ 1080p) and I can't focus on objects that are inside of its frame.

Pseudo code for what I'm doing:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton! // button centred on screen that requires focus

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.playerController.player = AVPlayer(url: myURL)
        self.playerController.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(self.playerController.view)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.button)
    }

    // ... functions that enable listeners and show/hide button when self.playerController.player rate changes
}
```

What I want is to be able to press pause, then swipe up to get focus on the button(s) instead of the seek bar and then swipe back down to the seek bar if needed. Much like the Apple Music application that comes with the tvOS.

Thanks.

Comment: Ever got this to work nicely? Am trying to do the same, but can't seem to get the jumping right between scrubber & button

Answer (score 1):

You can set desired custom vc with action items to `var customOverlayViewController: UIViewController? { get set }` of your `AVPlayerViewController` instance.
(available from **tvOS 13**)

Official documentation states:

> When the transport bar is hidden, the player view controller presents
> the overlay view controller’s view when a user swipes up on the Siri
> Remote during playback. Use this property to set a custom view
> controller instead of installing your own swipe gesture recognizer.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller/3229856-customoverlayviewcontroller

You can also check this video starting from **26:07** to see it in action.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/503

P.S. Don't use `var contentOverlayView: UIView? { get }` to display interactable content, as official documentation states:

> Use the content overlay view to add noninteractive custom views, such
> as a logo or watermark, between the video content and the controls.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller/1615835-contentoverlayview

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to override preferredFocusEnvironment and add some listeners to the parent VC to change a condition when certain actions are taken...not perfect but good enough.

```
override var preferredFocusEnvironment {
    if self.someCondition {
        return [self.button]
    }
    else {
        return [self.playerController.view]
    }
}
```